# iPhone IB's are not showing instead of iPad on View as section: Xcode 8

Tags: ipad, xib, xcode8

My application is compatible for iPad only but on **View as** console over xib its showing only iPhone IB.
[image]

Please suggest me how can we replace iPad IB manually.

Note-*I am not using Auto-layout in this Application*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found solution:

1:**If you are using Auto-layout and want to use iPhone and iPad both**

- Enable to Use Auto-Layout and Use trail variations.
  [image]
- Now check your view as section iPhone and iPad both are visible.
- [image: List item]

**2: If you are not using Auto-Layout and want to change from iPhone to iPad or Vise Versa**

- Enable to Use Auto-Layout and Use trail variations. (Same as above section).
- And again disable to both then one popup will appear as below image from that you can select you compatible device(iPhone or iPad).

[image]